# Configure kubectl command to access remote minikube cluster on virtualbox debian VM

Tags: networking, kubernetes, virtualbox, kubectl, minikube

i have set up successfully on debian minikube with simple cluster
Debian VM :

```
umen@debian12:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-77c947d946-jq2s4   1/1     Running   0          45m
hello-77c947d946-wm6n2   1/1     Running   0          45m

umen@debian12:~$ minikube service list -p multinode-demo
|-------------|------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |    NAME    | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|-------------|------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default     | hello      |           80 | http://192.168.49.2:31000 |
| default     | kubernetes | No node port |                           |
| kube-system | kube-dns   | No node port |                           |
|-------------|------------|--------------|---------------------------|

umen@debian12:~$ curl http://192.168.49.2:31000
Hello from hello-77c947d946-wm6n2 (10.244.1.2)
```

As you see above all working

now In my windows host i try to connect this cluster
i downloaded the certificates from the debian server

vi ./kube/config_debian

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: debian/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 08:54:23 IDT
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.31.2
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.49.2:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 08:54:23 IDT
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.31.2
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: debian/client.crt
    client-key: debian/client.key
```

when i try to connect im getting :

```
$ kubectl -v=8 --kubeconfig=config_debian get pods
I1023 10:55:55.058414   16936 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  config_debian
I1023 10:55:55.154616   16936 cert_rotation.go:137] Starting client certificate rotation controller
I1023 10:55:55.154616   16936 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s
I1023 10:55:55.155136   16936 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I1023 10:55:55.155136   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1023 10:55:55.155136   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl.exe/v1.22.0 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/c2b5237
I1023 10:56:16.186405   16936 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 21031 milliseconds
I1023 10:56:16.186405   16936 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I1023 10:56:16.186405   16936 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.49.2:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
I1023 10:56:16.188079   16936 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s
I1023 10:56:16.188079   16936 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I1023 10:56:16.188079   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1023 10:56:16.188079   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl.exe/v1.22.0 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/c2b5237
I1023 10:56:37.192081   16936 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 21003 milliseconds
I1023 10:56:37.192189   16936 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I1023 10:56:37.192189   16936 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.49.2:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
I1023 10:56:37.193955   16936 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.49.2:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
I1023 10:56:37.194510   16936 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://192.168.49.2:8443/api?timeout=32s
I1023 10:56:37.194510   16936 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I1023 10:56:37.195088   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1023 10:56:37.195088   16936 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl.exe/v1.22.0 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/c2b5237
```

and in virtual box i set the port forward like this :
[image]

The question is why i can't connect to the remote cluster

Comment: It seems the kubectl lost connection to the Cluster and you can set the Cluster context by following this [Troubleshooting kubectl command times out](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out). You can try to use the **kubectl proxy** to open local 8xxx for accessing the web interface of Kubernetes for more details refer to [How to Install Minikube on Debian](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-minikube-on-debian-11-bullseye-linux/).

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if my answer & comment helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions and the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Github issue #2575](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2575), check the causes for connection issues & mitigations as explained below :

1. Check you might have an issue with having both Docker Toolbox (old version using VirtualBox) and Docker for Windows (using Hyper-V) installed. Removing Docker Toolbox and re-installing Docker for Windows may help to resolve the issue.
2. Check the server’s resources running low : make sure the server has enough resources (such as memory) to handle the no.of requests you are sending.

From certification side try below 2 steps & follow the documentation [minikube TLS without verification](https://github.com/robertluwang/hands-on-docker/blob/master/minikube-no-tls-verify.md#how-to-disable-tls-verification-for-minikube), which may help to resolve your issue further :

1. Setup port forward from host 8443 to Minikube vm 8443 in virtualbox
2. Create a new context minikube-vpn without TLS verify.